# Count branches in queryset

Tags: django

Django==3.2

At a breakpoint I have such queryset:

```
<QuerySet [<UsingSemanticsLevelTwo: 2. Дубаец - 3. green_dubai_TR>, <UsingSemanticsLevelTwo: 2. Дубаец - 2. dubai_TR>, <UsingSemanticsLevelTwo: 1. Вас вызывает Дубай 1 - 4. dubai_COMP>]>
```

Model:

```
class UsingSemanticsLevelTwo(models.Model):
    branch = models.ForeignKey("clients.Branch",
                               on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                               blank=True,
                               null=True,
                               verbose_name=gettext("Branch"),
                               related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related",
                               related_query_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)ss", )
```

**Problem**

I want to count distinct branches in a queryset.

```
queryset.annotate(Count("branch"), distinct=True)
```

It blows up:

```
{TypeError}QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s): True.
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `distinct` is a keyword argument to `Count` not to `annotate`, hence your query should be:

```
queryset.annotate(Count("branch", distinct=True))
```

Instead of:

```
queryset.annotate(Count("branch"), distinct=True)
```

If there is a need to actually annotate a constant value it can be done by using a `Value` expression:

```
from django.db.models import Value


queryset.annotate(some_value=Value(True))
```

**Edit**: If you just want to aggregate data you need to use [`aggregate` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate) instead of `annotate` (Annotate would aggregate on on the results of a group by, while aggregate simply will aggregate all rows):

```
queryset.aggregate(Count("branch", distinct=True))['branch__count']
```

Comment: Pardon. But it returns a queryset. I want just a number - how many branches. Maybe I use annotate in vain. Could you help me count branches?